# setlocale does not give correct output

Tags: php

I'm trying to `setlocale` using PHP `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_EN')` and was told that code `echo money_format('%i', 123.45)` would show if it was set or not.

However the output is just: `123.45` so it seams that `setlocale` was never set?

Comment: setLocale() returns a Boolean false on failure, or a string containing the locale that you've set on success.... so pretty easy for you to test whether it's set the locale correctly or not: `if (setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_EN') === false) { echo "setLocale() failed"; }`

Comment: Ok, it return `setLocale() failed`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the name I was using was wrong. I checked the server running `sudo locale -a` and noticed that the Swedish package for instance was namned `sv_SE.utf8` so after changing to that the currency symbol did change. However `date`did not change in format.